# Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 and error 404

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

after Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 im get error 404 when send form :

```
 <form id="SpecialShowCreateForm" method="post"
                  asp-controller="SpecialShow"
                  asp-action="CreateSpecialShowAsync"
                  role="form"
                  data-ajax="true" ,
                  enctype="multipart/form-data"
                <div class="form-group">
                      <input asp-for="Caption" >
                </div>
            </form>

    [HttpPost]
    [AjaxOnly]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateSpecialShowAsync([FromForm]SpecialShowViewModel vm)
    {
        return Json(new { msg = ok });
    }
```

These codes are also inside the startup.cs file What changes are needed?
public class Startup
{
readonly IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

```
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Json").Build();
    }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Shop")));
        
        services.AddMvc();
        
        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
                     services.AddOptions();

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                "admin",
                "admin",
                "Admin/{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                "default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });  
    }
```

Comment: can you post your `Startup.cs` file ?

Comment: @Ali : https://filebin.net/u5e1yywxxhusryzt/Startup.cs?t=2w8ctw69

Comment: Edit the Startup.cs into your question. Links to code are not accepted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
The problem was naming the action, I deleted Async and the problem was solved !!!
It was very strange

```
 [HttpPost]
[AjaxOnly]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateSpecialShow([FromForm]SpecialShowViewModel vm)
{
    return Json(new { msg = ok });
}
```